# integrate BigBlueButton php API in Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bigbluebutton

I integrate BigBlueButton package using composer from githut (https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-api-php).

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-api-php": "dev-master"
},
```

There no providers or aliases details in the documentation.
How to add this providers and aliases details in the app.php page

Answer (score 1):

This package provides a Facade in Laravel for the BBB api:

https://github.com/ICTO/laravel-bigbluebutton

Answer (score 0):

The official BigBlueButton PHP API Client can be found at https://packagist.org/packages/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-api-php

A Laravel interface is also available at https://packagist.org/packages/eaglesistemas/bigbluebutton